# secondary key ("index" attribute) in data.table is lost when table is "copied" by selecting columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `myDT`, and I'm making "copies" of this table by 3 different ways:

```
myDT <- data.table(colA = 1:3)
myDT[colA == 3]

copy1 <- copy(myDT)
copy2 <- myDT # yes I know that it's a reference, not real copy
copy3 <- myDT[,.(colA)] # I list all columns from the original table
```

Then I'm comparing those copies with the original table:

```
identical(myDT, copy1) 
# TRUE
identical(myDT, copy2)
# TRUE
identical(myDT, copy3)
# FALSE
```

I was trying to figure out what was the difference between `myDT` and `copy3`

```
identical(names(myDT), names(copy3))
# TRUE
all.equal(myDT, copy3, check.attributes=FALSE)
# TRUE
all.equal(myDT, copy3, check.attributes=FALSE, trim.levels=FALSE, check.names=TRUE)
# TRUE
attr.all.equal(myDT, copy3, check.attributes=FALSE, trim.levels=FALSE, check.names=TRUE)
# NULL
all.equal(myDT, copy3)
# [1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"
attr.all.equal(myDT, copy3)
# [1] "Attributes: < Names: 1 string mismatch >"                                         
# [2] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 3 components >"                
# [3] "Attributes: < Component 3: Attributes: < Modes: list, NULL > >"                   
# [4] "Attributes: < Component 3: Attributes: < names for target but not for current > >"
# [5] "Attributes: < Component 3: Attributes: < current is not list-like > >"            
# [6] "Attributes: < Component 3: Numeric: lengths (0, 3) differ >"
```

My original question was how to understand the last output. Finally I came to using the `attributes()` function:

```
attr0 <- attributes(myDT)
attr3 <- attributes(copy3)
str(attr0)
str(attr3)
```

it has shown that original `data.table` had an `index` attribute which was not copied when I created `copy3`.

Comment: I think it is better to provide a reproducible example. If I create `myDT <- data.table(col1=1:3, col2=4:6, col3=7:9)`, it is giving me TRUE for all the cases.

Comment: yes, I also don't see that difference when I create dummy table, I see the effect only with my big table... I will try to reduce it and attach it here.

Comment: example is not reproducible

Comment: @jangorecki, there's a reproducible example in David's answer below.

Comment: @VasilyA great, if you accept it is a reproducible for your question that you could include it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make this question a bit clearer (and maybe useful for future readers), what really happened here is that you (probably not) set a *secondary key* while explicitly calling `set2key`, OR, `data.table` seemingly set a *secondary key* while you were making some ordinary operations such as filtering. This is a (not so) new feature added in V 1.9.4

> *DT[column==value] and DT[column %in% values] are now optimized to use
>   DT's key when key(DT)[1]=="column", otherwise a secondary key (a.k.a.
>   index) is automatically added so the next DT[column==value] is much
>   faster. No code changes are needed; existing code should automatically
>   benefit. Secondary keys can be added manually using set2key() and
>   existence checked using key2(). These optimizations and function
>   names/arguments are experimental and may be turned off with
>   options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE).*

---

Lets reproduce this

```
myDT <- data.table(A = 1:3)
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)
myDT[A == 3]    
# Creating new index 'A' <~~~~ Here it is
# forder took 0 sec
# Coercing double column i.'V1' to integer to match type of x.'A'. Please avoid coercion for efficiency.
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
# A
# 1: 3

attr(myDT, "index") # or using `key2(myDT)`
# integer(0)
# attr(,"__A")
# integer(0)
```

So, unlike you were assuming, you actually *did* create a copy and thus the secondary key wasn't transferred with it. Compare

```
copy1 <- myDT
attr(copy1, "index")
# integer(0)
# attr(,"__A")
# integer(0)
copy2 <- myDT[,.(A)]
# Detected that j uses these columns: A <~~~ This is where the copy occures
attr(copy2, "index")
# NULL

identical(myDT, copy1)
# [1] TRUE
identical(myDT, copy2)
# [1] FALSE
```

And for some further validation

```
tracemem(myDT)
# [1] "<00000000159CBBB0>"
tracemem(copy1)
# [1] "<00000000159CBBB0>"
tracemem(copy2)
# [1] "<000000001A5A46D8>"
```

---

The most interesting conclusion here, one could claim, that `[.data.table` *does* create a copy, even if the object remains unchanged.