# Problems with secondary key of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a reproducible example:

```
myDT <- data.table(ID=c('A','B','B'), val=c('check','check','a'));
myDT[val == "check"]; # <= secondary index created on calling this
myDT[, val:=ifelse(.N>1, '2', '1'), by=ID]

myDT
#    ID val
# 1:  A   1
# 2:  B   2
# 3:  B   2

key(myDT)
# NULL
key2(myDT) 
# [1] "val"
```

Now, I call a simple command that gives rather strange (for me) result:

```
myDT[val=='2', res:='yes'][];
#    ID val res
# 1:  A   1  NA
# 2:  B   2 yes
# 3:  B   2  NA
```

With filter `val=='2'`, I expected to get records 2 and 3, but in fact I got only record 3. This is obviously due to the secondary key because its removal brings back expected behavior:

```
set2key(myDT, NULL)
myDT[val=='2', res:='yes'][];
#    ID val res
# 1:  A   1  NA
# 2:  B   2 yes
# 3:  B   2 yes
```

I am wondering if it's a bug or expected behavior. In my case, it was obviously not desired: I did not even know about such thing as secondary key (before asking [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977413/secondary-key-index-attribute-in-data-table-is-lost-when-table-is-copied-b)), and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why I miss some records. For me, I solved the problem by adding `set2key(myDT, NULL)` instruction but now I am worrying that similar thing could happen in some other parts of my code and I don't know how to detect/prevent it - I wouldn't like to add `set2key(., NULL)` calls after every other line...

Comment: It seems like some type of a bug indeed. It seems that it is being caused by changing the values of the column the secondary key is set upon without updating the secondary key itself. but I'm usually wrong regarding these things. Worth posting an [issue on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new)

Comment: thanks for support, I will post it then. I am wondering if my code can be even further simplified to make a minimal example.

Comment: Yes, you can do something like `myDT <- data.table(ID=c('A','B','B'), val=c('check','check','a')) ; myDT[val == "check"] ; myDT[, val := ifelse(.N>1, '2', '1'), by = ID] ; myDT[val=='2']`. It seems like something related to changing the values in the key while doing it by group combined with `ifelse`. You found some very specific scenario they haven't thought of it seems.

Comment: oh, I don't need all this mess with another function indeed! thanks for pointing out, I will remove it from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was indeed a bug (I reported it but it turned out to be reported already), and it was fixed in package version 1.9.7 - now everything works!